# Push notification are not receiving

Tags: java, android, push-notification, urbanairship.com, error-console

I'm using sample application given by Urban Airship Documentation page. It's working fine to be executed and fetching the ApId as per screenshot. I've created application on [urbanairship official wesite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWktq.png)

But i am not able to send a test notification while it displays a message "We sent a message successfully" after doing test Notification but there in no notification received at my Device. I am using Samsung Galaxy S3. There is an error found in Console "Received push with invalid authorization on platform GCM" While i am sure i've added valid development key and secret key. Can any body suggest me if i am missing something. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here below is my DDMS log:-

```
    02-21 12:15:45.229: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Adding event: {"data":{"class_name":"com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.MainActivity","session_id":"c56c9602-2f7b-47b3-b524-7a9f3971185b"},"type":"activity_started","event_id":"fb0287f3-dd52-4f06-8fb5-3e7f150ffadd","time":"1392965145"}
02-21 12:15:45.239: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): New session: 69f3facf-5cf7-4ff1-ba82-a653bdf4ff74
02-21 12:15:45.264: I/Push Sample - UALib(970): LocationService is not bound to MainActivity
02-21 12:15:45.264: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Adding event: {"data":{"time_zone":19800,"session_id":"69f3facf-5cf7-4ff1-ba82-a653bdf4ff74","notification_types":["sound","vibrate"],"daylight_savings":false,"push_enabled":true,"carrier":"AIRCEL","lib_version":"3.3.0","connection_type":"wifi","package_version":"1.0","os_version":"4.1.2"},"type":"app_foreground","event_id":"d63a865b-0cbf-456e-af38-a263c0ed91d3","time":"1392965145"}
02-21 12:15:45.269: I/System.out(970): ###apidString===a58be1a8-986c-4913-8f52-6d69e937137d
02-21 12:15:45.274: D/dalvikvm(970): GC_CONCURRENT freed 379K, 14% free 13010K/15047K, paused 25ms+11ms, total 90ms
02-21 12:15:45.284: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.urbanairship.analytics.APP_FOREGROUND
02-21 12:15:45.344: D/dalvikvm(970): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
02-21 12:15:45.369: D/dalvikvm(970): GC_EXPLICIT freed 123K, 15% free 12905K/15047K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 27ms
02-21 12:16:05.794: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Saving preference: com.urbanairship.analytics.LAST_SEND value: 1392965165802
02-21 12:16:05.809: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Notifying of change to content://com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.urbanairship.provider/preferences/com.urbanairship.analytics.LAST_SEND/insert
02-21 12:16:05.809: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Preference updated:com.urbanairship.analytics.LAST_SEND
02-21 12:16:05.819: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Set Timeout: 60000
02-21 12:16:05.819: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Set Socket Buffer Size: 16384
02-21 12:16:05.819: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): GZIP'd: 857 into 331 (expected 214)
02-21 12:16:05.824: I/Push Sample - UALib(970): Sending 4 events.
02-21 12:16:05.824: I/Push Sample - UALib(970): Sending Analytics to: https://combine.urbanairship.com/warp9/
02-21 12:16:08.644: I/Push Sample - UALib(970): Uploading events: [{"data":{"class_name":"com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.MainActivity","session_id":"618905ca-c5c6-41a5-8df2-88249bf713a6"},"type":"activity_stopped","event_id":"9a3e0903-c962-4193-b934-2c7d62193754","time":"1392964900"}, {"data":{"class_name":"com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.MainActivity","session_id":"618905ca-c5c6-41a5-8df2-88249bf713a6"},"type":"activity_started","event_id":"53a5b81c-8739-49f5-ab77-f075dd340aba","time":"1392964909"}, {"data":{"class_name":"com.urbanairship.push.sample.preference.PreferencesActivity","session_id":"618905ca-c5c6-41a5-8df2-88249bf713a6"},"type":"activity_stopped","event_id":"f0afdb5b-fc7c-40c3-affd-fbe0290c8088","time":"1392964870"}, {"data":{"connection_type":"wifi","session_id":"618905ca-c5c6-41a5-8df2-88249bf713a6"},"type":"app_background","event_id":"90f44fd3-354c-449f-9e36-f8f5a9eb3c13","time":"1392964902"}]
02-21 12:16:08.654: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Scheduling next event batch upload.
02-21 12:16:08.679: I/Push Sample - UALib(970): Warp 9 response: 200
02-21 12:16:08.679: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Preference already up to date
02-21 12:16:08.679: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Preference already up to date
02-21 12:16:08.679: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Saving preference: com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_WAIT value: 604800000
02-21 12:16:08.694: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Notifying of change to content://com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.urbanairship.provider/preferences/com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_WAIT/insert
02-21 12:16:08.694: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Preference updated:com.urbanairship.analytics.MAX_WAIT
02-21 12:16:08.699: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Preference already up to date
02-21 12:16:15.099: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Adding event: {"data":{"class_name":"com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.MainActivity","session_id":"69f3facf-5cf7-4ff1-ba82-a653bdf4ff74"},"type":"activity_stopped","event_id":"d697c9c9-b887-48ca-8c58-3ba600431986","time":"1392965175"}
02-21 12:16:15.139: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(970): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
02-21 12:16:15.139: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(970): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
02-21 12:16:15.139: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(970): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
02-21 12:16:17.119: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Adding event: {"data":{"connection_type":"wifi","session_id":"69f3facf-5cf7-4ff1-ba82-a653bdf4ff74"},"type":"app_background","event_id":"0da72dc6-9b2c-4668-bf7f-885f33ecb888","time":"1392965177"}
02-21 12:16:17.119: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.urbanairship.analytics.APP_BACKGROUND
02-21 12:16:33.024: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Adding event: {"data":{"class_name":"com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.MainActivity","session_id":"69f3facf-5cf7-4ff1-ba82-a653bdf4ff74"},"type":"activity_started","event_id":"b6fc22f8-cd78-4184-a43e-4bcc66f4cbc8","time":"1392965193"}
02-21 12:16:33.024: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): New session: 6538e799-dfc6-4324-9ac6-996f5abb66e1
02-21 12:16:33.054: I/Push Sample - UALib(970): LocationService is not bound to MainActivity
02-21 12:16:33.069: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): Adding event: {"data":{"time_zone":19800,"session_id":"6538e799-dfc6-4324-9ac6-996f5abb66e1","notification_types":["sound","vibrate"],"daylight_savings":false,"push_enabled":true,"carrier":"AIRCEL","lib_version":"3.3.0","connection_type":"wifi","package_version":"1.0","os_version":"4.1.2"},"type":"app_foreground","event_id":"f3def7d3-31c0-49fb-8ec8-a8d11f9a0059","time":"1392965193"}
02-21 12:16:33.094: I/System.out(970): ###apidString===a58be1a8-986c-4913-8f52-6d69e937137d
02-21 12:16:33.144: V/Push Sample - UALib(970): com.urbanairship.push.sample.abc.urbanairship.analytics.APP_FOREGROUND
```